# Store then Send API response

Tags: angular, ionic4

So, after logging in, the API answers three parameters: name, email and token. To validate the courses the user is subscribed to, I have to pass (post) 2 parameters, token and course, so the API answers which courses the user is subscribed to. I'm storing the token this way in the login.ts page:

```
userLogin(){
    this.authloginService.logarConta(this.email, this.password).then((result)=>{

      localStorage.setItem('token', result['token'])
      console.log(result['token']);
      this.navCtrl.navigateForward('inicio')

     });
```

service.ts page:

```
logarConta(email: string, password:string){

      email = encodeURIComponent(email);
      password = encodeURIComponent(password);

      var data = `email=${email}&password=${password}`;

    return this.http.post('https://api.elainneourives.com.br/api/login', data, {headers: this.headers}).toPromise();

  }
```

How can I send the token variable to valitade the courses?

API Service request to get the courses:

```
getCourses(token:string, course:string){

    token = encodeURIComponent (token);
    course = encodeURIComponent (course);

      var cursos = `token=${token}&course=${course}`;

      return this.http.post('https://myapi.com/api/subscriptions', cursos , {headers: this.headers}).toPromise();

  }
```

Comment: Where is the api service request code for getting the course s

Comment: Just eddited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
token = encodeURIComponent (localStorage.getItem('token'));
```

Like this way you can access it